# Parse.com crash reporting: stack trace is not symbolicated

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

We use the Parse.com crash reporting. It was straightforward to integrate, the uploading of symbol information works (success message in log file) and the crash reports arrive on Parse.com web site.

However, the stack trace contains mangled names and no line information for our own code as if we had not uploaded the symbol information, e.g.:

```
0    CoreFoundation    __exceptionPreprocess @ 0x84
1    libobjc.A.dylib   objc_exception_throw @ 0x38
2    CoreFoundation    -[NSException raise] @ 0x8
3    MyApp             _TToFC9MyApp23TestViewController13viewDidAppearfS0_FSbT_ @ 0x1f4
4    UIKit             -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] @ 0x24c
```

The uploading of the symbol information was successful. Otherwise the crash report would contain the warning: *This stack trace is unsymbolicated. To obtain symbols...* But we don't get that warning.

Could it be related to some compiler settings in release mode (we only upload symbols for release builds)? Or what could be the cause of the unsymbolicated stack traces?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: No, still not working.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume that you're using Swift? - If so, then there's an excellent write up on the Mike Ash blog about why and how this happens: https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-08-15-swift-name-mangling.html

You can also demangle the names by launching terminal and running `xcrun swift-demangle SYM` - but you need to do this on the same version of the swift compiler as you compiled the application with.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: That's not exactly what I want to achieve. I'd like to upload sufficient symbol information to parse.com so I can see a detailed stack trace there, without mangled names and including line information.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't possible at the moment.

Comment: Is this a restriction of Swift, of Apple's tools or of Parse.com?

Comment: This is a restriction mostly of Swift/Apple's Tools.

Comment: If that's so: why do other products such a Crashlytics/Fabric and Apple's crash reporting in TestFlight show the line information? Can you be more specific about what's supposedly missing in Apple's Swift tools?

Comment: I'm referring to the mangling limitation. Line information may just be an issue with the Parse crash reporter.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the Strip Debug Symbols During copy to "No":
[image]

I'm not sure if those next settings can help you or not, but just try to set to NO for 2 other settings: "Strip Linked Product" and "Deployment Postprocessing"

[image]

Then, if it still does not work, test your application in debug mode.

Comment: That would make sense. It's on "Yes" for release builds currently. I'll let you know later if it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, it only works for Objective-C code. There I have line information. But for Swift code, there is no change: the names are mangled and the line information is missing.

Comment: Your answer didn't really help but I'm awarding you the bounty as it's somewhat better than Daniel Tomlinson's.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents are that you're sending a message to a deallocated object but without the complete stack trace can't be sure.

Comment: The question is: why is the stack trace not symbolicated. I know why it crashes because I caused it purposely for testing the crash reporting.